# My phone is stuck next to my drive. I cannot remove it even though it isn't even plugged in

Tags: windows-10

Next to my HardDrive C: is something called Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge. I created it by mistake some months ago when I tried to do some stuff, but couldn't remove it in any way. Right clicking only gives me the options to create a shortcut or to pin it to the start menu. Double click doesn't do anything.

Edit: To clarify, I am not talking about my phone physically, but it is stuck as a drive for some reason. [If you look here you should know what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF2YD.png) I don't want to remove my actual phone, just the thing that is shown here and called S7Edge.

Comment: Your question is nonsensical.  Your phone is a physical object.  You might want to rephrase it so it is clear what "My phone" implies.  You might tell us what you have tried to fix it, and provide screenshots.  (Have you tried removing the software from the computer - assuming it is a software problem)

Comment: @davidgo Sorry, updated my question. I hope it is clearer now. It is not any program btw.

Comment: is your phone plugged into your computer? does the icon disappear when you unplug it?

Comment: @Tomhawk: Try going to **Devices and Printers** and see if it is listed in there. If so then right-click and choose **Remove device**.

Comment: @FrankThomas As stated in the title it is not plugged in. If I plug it in it pops up there as a third icon with the same name.

Comment: @JamesP doing that shows me an "Error while removing" as the state of the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you try going on Device Manager which you can get on by typing in the search bar. You need to be an admin to make changes. Select Portable Devices and your phone should be listed.

Once there try the following steps.

1. Seeing from the description if the device is working properly.
2. Try updating the driver if it needs it
3. Try rolling bag the driver or uninstalling and reinstalling.